# Swift Codable: Continue parsing object after nested object error

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

My app is, like oh so many apps, retrieving JSON from an API and converting it using the new `Codable` protocol in Swift 4. Most of the time, this works fine and as expected. However, sometimes the API will send me unexpected garbage. Incorrect types, arrays with just `null` inside, that kind of thing.

The problem is that the objects involved can be large and complicated, and when I'm parsing a child object and it fails, the whole object fails, all the way up to the root. I'm including a very simple playground example to illustrate the concept; the actual objects involved are way more complex.

```
let goodJSON = """
{
    "name": "Fiona Glenanne",
    "vehicles": [
        {
            "make": "Saab",
            "model": "9-3",
            "color": "Black"
        },
        {
            "make": "Hyundai",
            "model": "Genesis",
            "color": "Blue"
        }
    ]
}
"""
let goodJSONData = goodJSON.data(using: .utf8)!

let badJSON = """
{
    "name": "Michael Westen",
    "vehicles": {
        "make": "Dodge",
        "model": "Charger",
        "color": "Black"
    }
}
"""
let badJSONData = badJSON.data(using: .utf8)!

struct Character: Codable {
    let name: String
    let vehicles: [Vehicle]
}
struct Vehicle: Codable {
    let make: String
    let model: String
    let color: String
}

do {
    let goodCharacter = try JSONDecoder().decode(Character.self, from: goodJSONData)
    print(goodCharacter)
} catch {
    print(error)
}

do {
    let badCharacter = try JSONDecoder().decode(Character.self, from: badJSONData)
    print(badCharacter)
} catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(let type, let context) {
    print("Got \(type); \(context.debugDescription) ** Path:\(context.codingPath)")
} catch {
    print("Caught a different error: \(error)")
}
```

Output:

```
Character(name: "Fiona Glenanne", vehicles: [__lldb_expr_20.Vehicle(make: "Saab", model: "9-3", color: "Black"), __lldb_expr_20.Vehicle(make: "Hyundai", model: "Genesis", color: "Blue")])
Got Array<Any>; Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead. ** Path:[CodingKeys(stringValue: "vehicles", intValue: nil)]
```

`vehicles` is expected to be an array of objects, but in the `badJSON` case, it is a single object, which causes the `.typeMismatch` exception and kills the parsing right there.

What I'm looking for is a way to allow errors like this one to kill the parsing for *the child object only* and allow parsing of the parent object to continue. I'm looking to do this in a generic fashion, so I don't have to special case each and every object in my app to specifically handle whatever bad data the API delivers. I'm not sure if there even is a solution for this, I haven't had any luck finding anything, but it would sure improve my quality of life if there is. Thanks!

Comment: You have to write a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)` initializer to handle the cases. By the way: **Never** use `Character` as a custom struct name. This could cause a terminology clash with [Character](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character). And if you can blame the owner of the service to send consistent data.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the response. The issue with doing a custom initializer is that I don't know exactly _how_ the API is going to send me malformed data. It just sometimes does. Trying to code against that defensively is probably a losing battle, so I'm trying to just snag the error and allow it to fail the nested object and continue on with the parent in a generic way. Also good point with the Character name; this is just an example of my issue and is not real code.

Comment: at any point in bad JSON do u always know what is going to be bad ?

Comment: @MikeGlass please check my answer and mark if it was what u need

Answer (score 1):

you can try to custom the init(from decoder: Decoder) as suggested in comments it would be something like this,

```
struct Character: Codable {
let name: String
let vehicles: [Vehicle]
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name, vehicles }

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    do {
        let vehicle = try container.decode(Vehicle.self, forKey: .vehicles)
        vehicles = [vehicle]
    } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
        vehicles = try container.decode([Vehicle].self, forKey: .vehicles)
    }
}
```